# How can I get the file name from request.FILES?

Tags: django, django-forms

How can I get the file name from request.FILES in Django?

```
def upload(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UploadForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            upload = Upload()
            upload.timestamp = datetime.datetime.now()
            save_instance(form, upload)
```

I tried using this but it did not work:

```
  if 'filename'  in request.FILES:
         filename = request.FILES['filename']
```

Answer (score 137, accepted):

```
request.FILES['filename'].name
```

From the [`request`](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.FILES) documentation.

If you don't know the key, you can iterate over the files:

```
for filename, file in request.FILES.iteritems():
    name = request.FILES[filename].name
```

Comment: it gives me : expected an indented block. I confuse :(

Comment: ok! how can i check variable name? but i need print it how can i print what is inside?

Comment: This is what worked for me: request.FILES['file'].name

Comment: `request.FILES` is a multivalue dictionary like object that keeps the files uploaded through a upload file button. Say in your html the name of the button (tyep="file") is "myfile" so my file will be the key in this dictionary. If you uploaded one file, then the value for this key will be only one and if you uploade dmultiple files, then you will have multiple values for that specific key. if you use `request.FILES['myfile'] you will get the first or last value (I cannot say for sure). This is fine if you only uploaded one file, if you want to get all files you should do this:

Comment: iteritems() was removed in python3, so you can't use this method anymore. .items() instead of .iteritems()

Answer (score 80):

```
file = request.FILES['filename']
file.name           # Gives name
file.content_type   # Gives Content type text/html etc
file.size           # Gives file's size in byte
file.read()         # Reads file
```

Comment: how can i get the path?

Comment: request.FILES['filename'].file.name

Comment: @AbdulRehman there is no 'path'. The file is uploaded and is now in memory. It has only a name.

Answer (score 22):

**NOTE if you are using python 3.x:**

`request.FILES` is a multivalue dictionary like object that keeps the files uploaded through an upload file button. Say in your html code the name of the button (type="file") is "myfile" so "myfile" will be the key in this dictionary. If you uploaded one file, then the value for this key will be only one and if you uploaded multiple files, then you will have multiple values for that specific key. If you use `request.FILES['myfile']` you will get the first or last value (I cannot say for sure). This is fine if you only uploaded one file, but if you want to get all files you should do this:

```
list=[] #myfile is the key of a multi value dictionary, values are the uploaded files
for f in request.FILES.getlist('myfile'): #myfile is the name of your html file button
    filename = f.name
    list.append(filename)
```

of course one can squeeze the whole thing in one line, but this is easy to understand

Answer (score 7):

The answer may be outdated, since there is a `name` property on the `UploadedFile` class. See: [Uploaded Files and Upload Handlers (Django docs)](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/files/uploads/#django.core.files.uploadedfile.UploadedFile.name). So, if you bind your form with a `FileField` correctly, the access should be as easy as:

```
if form.is_valid():
    form.cleaned_data['my_file'].name
```

Answer (score 5):

Worked for me on Python 3.8, Django 3.2

```
print(request.FILES.items())
for filename, file in request.FILES.items():
    print(filename, file)
```

`request.FILES.iteritems()` was throwing `AttributeError` for me.