# How to get file name in UpdateView (Create View) in Django

Tags: django

I got a simple model,.

`models.py`:

```
class Inform_note(models.Model):
id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
in_note_on = models.FileField(upload_to='notes', blank=True)
note_date = models.DateField(auto_now_add=False, blank=True, null=True)
```

With CreateView I can create a new records, edit this records with my UpdateView, add files etc...

`view.py`:

```
class Inform_noteEditView(generic.UpdateView):
model = Inform_note
fields = '__all__'


def get_form(self, form_class=None):
    form = super().get_form(form_class)
    form.helper = FormHelper()
    form.helper.add_input(Submit('submit', 'Create', css_class='btn-primary'))
    form.fields['in_note_on'].label = "Выписка об ОН"
    return form
```

But before 'return form' i want to see a filename in field (in_note_on).

```
print(form.fields['in_note_on'])
```

returns `<django.forms.fields.FileField object at 0x00000000062D9710>`

Any ideas how to get file name in this field ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By this get_object function i have access to objects in model.

```
queryset = Inform_note.objects.all()
def get_object(self):
    ob = super().get_object()
    print(ob.in_note_on)
```

Now view.py:

```
class Inform_noteEditView(generic.UpdateView):
model = Inform_note
fields = '__all__'

queryset = Inform_note.objects.all()
def get_object(self):
    ob = super().get_object()
    print(ob.in_note_on)


def get_form(self, form_class=None):
    form = super().get_form(form_class)
    form.helper = FormHelper()
    form.helper.add_input(Submit('submit', 'Create', css_class='btn-primary'))
    form.fields['in_note_on'].label = "MY FILE"
    return form
```

Answer (score 0):

```
file_name=form.fields['in_note_on'].name  
print(file_name)
```

It will print the uploaded filename. For more info follow below link:
[How can I get the file name from request.FILES?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3111779/how-can-i-get-the-file-name-from-request-files)

Comment: Exception Value: 'FileField' object has no attribute 'name'.  I upload files by CreateView form.

Comment: Have you checked link??

Comment: Please try form.in_note_on.name

Comment: AttributeError: 'Inform_noteForm' object has no attribute 'in_note_on'