# How to take txt file as input into python (flask)

Tags: python, html, flask, request

Apologies in advance if this is easy but I cant figure it out.

I have a flask app which takes a txt file as an input on a webpage. I then want to run some python scripts on it and then export it back to the website user. I'm pretty much there but I just cant figure out how to get the txt file into python.

HTML

```
    <div class="file_input">
        <form action="." method="POST">
            <input type="file" name = "txt_file"> 
            <input type="submit" name="submit_form">
        </form>
    </div>
```

Python (Flask)

```
@app.route('/landing')
def landing():
    return render_template('index.html',
                           PageTitle = "Landing page")

@app.route('/', methods = ['POST'])
def test():
    text_file = request.form['txt_file']
    book_io = open(text_file, "r", encoding = "UTF-8")
    book_str = book_io.read()
    book_str
    return book_str
```

This isn't working as it's just taking the inputted text file as a string and then printing out this string.

I basically need to know how to import the text from the file into python, but I cant figure out how.

Thanks a lot in advance!!

Comment: did you checked `request.FILES` ? reference link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3111779/how-can-i-get-the-file-name-from-request-files

Comment: Hey mate, thanks for this. Yeah i did but I've just realised that I needed to add 'stream'. Such that the Python code is like this :     text = request.files['txt_file']
    text = text.stream.read(). Thanks for your help!!